# What are the relative merits of pdflatex?

Tags: pdf, latex, tex, pdflatex

Not sure this is a programming question, but we use LaTeX for all our API documentation and user documentation, so I hope it will go through.

Can someone please explain what are the relative merits of using `pdflatex` as opposed to the "classic" technique of

```
latex foo
dvips -Ppdf foo
ps2pdf foo.ps
```

From time to time I run into people who have difficulty because things don't work in `pdflatex`, and I know that using `pdflatex` gives up two things I have grown to value:

- Can't use the very speedy `xdvi` viewer
- Can't use the PStricks package

I should add that I typically get PDF with hyperlinks by using something on the order of

```
\usepackage[ps2pdf,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

so it's not necessary to use `pdflatex` to get good PDF.

So

1. What are the advantages of `pdflatex` that I don't know about?
2. What are the disadvantages of the old tools that I've overlooked?

Comment: You got lots of good answers here, but you can also check out the [TeX Stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).  See for instance [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-latex-and-pdflatex).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My favorite pdflatex feature is the [microtype package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/), which is available only when using pdflatex to go directly to PDF, and really produces stunning results with no effort on my part. Apart from that, the only caveats I run into are image formats:

- pdflatex supports PDF, PNG, and JPG images.
- the postscript drivers support (at least) EPS.

Also, if you want to install fonts, the procedures are slightly different depending on what fonts that driver supports. (Hint: use [XeTeX](http://scripts.sil.org/xetex) to instantly enable OpenType fonts.)

Comment: Yeah, the biggest difference is probably in image support. pdflatex supports all the common image formats, but not eps, while you otherwise get eps, and nothing else.

Comment: @jleedev: would you be kind enough to elaborate a little on what microtype does for you?  The README file went into some deep technicalities of typography...

Comment: I just say `\usepackage[kerning,spacing]{microtype}` which enables glyph scaling and margin kerning. You can browse the other options, but this is basically all you need.

Comment: And the benefit?  Output looks better?

Comment: Pretty much. The majority of your hyphens will disappear, making for smoother comprehension, and the right-side margin will be smoother.

Comment: Mmm.  Less hyphenation.  Nice.

Comment: @jalf:  Not to mention that pdflatex directly embeds JPG and PNG images in the PDF bytestream without recompression.  I like to run all my images through optipng and advpng for the final version.

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading since XeTeX unfortunately doesn’t support pdftex’ microtypographic extensions. :-(

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, I recently read a [post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/pdflatex-microtype/) that shows the difference directly.  Any document that uses tables or narrow columns will be improved automatically.  I also find the inter-word spacing to be far more pleasing with `pdflatex`.

Is `xdvi` much faster than `xpdf`?  I find the edit, `TeX`, view cycle to be very quick with `pdflatex`.

Have you tried MetaPost or MetaFun for graphics?  I tend to put graphics creation in the hands of the capable, but MetaFun would likely be the package I'd use.  Just reading the [manuals](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mchart.pdf) is a pleasure.

Comment: xdvi is not only much faster than xpdf, it is infinitely easier to look at, with full antialiasing &c.  The only competition is Adobe Reader on a *really* fast machine.

Comment: In my youth I used MetaFont and MetaPost extensively, but in my old age I prefer to put the ink where I want it to go (as opposed to figuring out what constraint to write).

Comment: Note that I pointed to MetaFun, not MetaFont.  But I certainly claim no special knowledge of either.  I just play around with them.

Answer (score 3):

Also pdftex is the engine under development (towards luatex) and maintenance. I'm not sure the DVI counterparts are as actively maintained.

PStricks is supplanted by Tikz.

I didn't use xdvi in years, so pardon the trollish rhetorical questions: Does xdvi display vector fonts? Does it support synctex (jumping to and from code)? Does it have the confort of use of PDF readers like Skim?

Comment: xdvi manages vector fonts and embedded EPS just fine.  I live in the Linux ghetto, not the OSX ghetto, so I'm not qualified to compare with synctex or Skim.  xdvi does work nicely with \usepackage{hyperref}.

Comment: It's not accurate to say that pstricks is supplanted by Tikz, but Tikz/PGF is at least a promising alternative (more portable, perhaps better designed, but less expressive).

Comment: OK :) To be honest, I prefer graphics editors to programming, it's less work to obtain a good enough result, and easier to make visual adjustments (I did write pretty complex povray objects in the past though).

As for synctex, maybe evince supports it?

Answer (score 1):

Taco Hoekwater is working on [Escrito](http://escrito.luatex.org/), a Postscript interpreter written in Lua, which would allow you to use pstricks in Luatex.  He has an impressive project completion record: maybe I should have used "will" rather than "would" in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I used pdflatex to generate the PDF for my ICFP 2009 paper. (I still needed to use standard latex to generate the PostScript file.) I did so for two reasons:

1. I couldn't seem to get ps2pdf to generate Letter, rather than A4 output, no matter what command line options I used.
2. For the printers, I needed to produce a version 1.3 PDF file, not 1.4. pdflatex made this easy to do. I set the PDF author and title information while I was at it.

Both of these problems may be fixable in some way, but as a first-time latex user, I didn't find any obvious solutions, nor did more experienced users whom I'd asked.

Comment: Interesting.  Linux explicitly offers `ps2pdf13` and `ps2pdf12`, which generate legacy PDFs.  The A4 output sounds more like a default TeX configuration out of the box; I have to run `texconfig` to change the default paper size.  But if you are on Windows, that's a closed book to me.